# WSO2 ESB High Availability/ clustering Environment system requirements

Tags: wso2-esb

I want information on the WSO2 ESB clustering system requirements for production deployment on Linux.

Went through the following link :[ESB clustering](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+ESB)

Understand that more than 1 copy of the WSO2 ESB would be extracted and set up on single server for Worker nodes  and similarly on the other server for Manager (DepSyn and admin) , worker nodes .

Can someone suggest what would be the system requirements of each server in this case ?

[system prerequisites](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Installation+Prerequisites) link suggests 
Memory -  2 GB , 1 GB Heap size
Disk - 1 GB
assuming to handle one ESB instance (worker or manager node).

Thanks in advance,
Sai.

Answer (score 0):

As a minimum, the system requirement would be 2 GB for the ESB worker JVM (+appropriate memory for the OS: assume 2GB for Linux in this case) which would be 4 GB minimum. Of course based on the type of work done and load, this requirement might increase.

The worker manager separation is for the separation of concerns. Hence in a typical production deployment, you *might* have a single manager node (same specs) and 2 worker nodes where only the worker nodes would handle traffic.